# Maven Project erro Relative Path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom

Tenho que dar manutenção em um sistema em `java` com `Maven`. Porem o sistema tem 3 projetos onde um se referencia com o outro, já tentei alterar o `build path` adicionando projetos e etc. Até agora nada abaixo segue o arquivo `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.org.MyCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>inscricoes-cursos-backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>inscricoes-backend</name>
    <parent> <!-- esta apresentando erro aqui nesta linha -->
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic.archetype</groupId>
        <artifactId>wls-common</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.org.MyCompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>gerador-boleto</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.org.MyCompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>gerador-boleto</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>inscricoes-cursos-backend</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
                <!-- You can find and redefine the following variables in the parent 
                    pom file. oracleMiddlewareHome oracleServerUrl oracleUsername oraclePassword 
                    oracleServerName -->
                <configuration>
                    <middlewareHome>${oracleMiddlewareHome}</middlewareHome>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!--Deploy the application to the server -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <user>******</user>
                            <password>*****</password>                  <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
                            <target>ms_2</target>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

O erro apresentando na linha de `parent` diz o seguinte.

> "Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   br.org.MyCompany:inscricoes-cursos-backend:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to
>   find com.oracle.weblogic.archetype:wls-common:pom:
>    12.1.3-0-0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are   forced and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM"

Acho que tem que alterar alguma coisa nessa pasta `.M2` mas não sei o que.

provavelmente rodar um comando parecido com esse:

```
mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3.jar -DoracleHome=/Users/edwin/Oracle/JDevMiddleware12.1.3
```

Não faço a minima ideia do que esse comando esta fazendo portanto não sei o que alterar nele se for isso mesmo.

Comment: Este grupo `parent` indica que seu projeto, está herdando características do projeto `com.oracle.weblogic.archetype:wls-common`. O erro quer dizer que esta projeto não está sendo encontrado no repositório do `maven` que você está usando. Não sei do que se trata este archetype. Dando uma "googleada", aparece algo do tipo: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#WLPRG585. Parece um bom ponto de partida. Antes de começar a dar manutenção em algum sistema, recomendo que você tente ao menos entender do que se trata.

Answer (score 2):

Ok obrigado pessoal encontrei uma solução para meu problema basicamente foi instalar manualmente os plugins do weblogic 12.1.3, abaixo uma descrição completa de como eu fiz isso caso alguém passe por essa mesma situação.

Primeiro de tudo configurei as variáveis de ambiente do maven: 
`M2_HOME` como abaixo.(`C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0` <-- onde meu maven esta instalado)

[image: maven variaveis de ambiente]

Então eu usei a variável criado na variável path como abaixo (processo bem similar a configuração das variáveis de ambiente do java)

[image: maven path]

agora posso usar o comando mvn no prompt de comando

entao eu fui para a pasta `C:\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\plugins\maven\com\oracle\maven\oracle-maven-sync\12.1.3` (aqui é onde meu weblogic esta instalado, entao eu rodei os comandos abaixo)

```
mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3.jar

mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=C:\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home -DoverwriteParent=true

mvn help:describe -DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic -DartifactId=weblogic-maven-plugin -Dversion=12.1.3-0-0
```

atenção especial para o segundo comando onde você tem que usar a oracle home que pode estar em diferentes lugares para cada caso.